# Hadoop MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput throws "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using Hadoop 0.20.203.0. I want to output to two different files, so I'm trying to get MultipleOutputs working.

Here's my configuration method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
  System.err.println("Usage: indycascade <in> <out>");
  System.exit(2);
}
Job job = new Job(conf, "indy cascade");
job.setJarByClass(IndyCascade.class);
job.setMapperClass(ICMapper.class);
job.setCombinerClass(ICReducer.class);
job.setReducerClass(ICReducer.class);

TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(conf, "sql", TextOutputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class);

job.waitForCompletion(true);
System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

However, this won't compile. The offending line is `MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(...)`, which throws a "cannot find symbol" error.

```
isaac/me/saac/i/IndyCascade.java:94: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method addNamedOutput(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<org.apa che.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat>,java.lang.Class<org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable>,java.lang.Class<org.apache.hadoop.io.Text>)
location: class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleOutputs
    MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput(conf, "sql", TextOutputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class);
```

Of course, I tried using a JobConf instead of Configuration, as the API demands, but that leads to the same error. Additionally, JobConf is deprecated.

How do I get MultipleOutputs to work? Is that even the correct class to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing old and new API types:

You're using the old API `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleOutputs`:

```
location: class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultipleOutputs
```

With the new API `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat`:

```
symbol  : method addNamedOutput(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,java.lang.String,java.lang.Class<org.apa che.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat>,java.lang.Class<org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable>,java.lang.Class<org.apache.hadoop.io.Text>)
```

Make the APIs consistent and you should be ok

**Edit:** Infact 0.20.203 doesn't have a port of MultipleOutputs for the new API, so you'll have to use the old api, find a new API port online [Cloudera- 0.20.2+320](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/hadoop-0.20.2+320.releasenotes.html)), or port it yourself

Also, you should look at the ToolRunner class to execute your jobs, it will remove the need to explicitly call the GenericOptionsParser:

```
public static class Driver extends Configured implements Tool {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.exit(ToolRunner.run(new Driver(), args));
  }

  public int run(String args[]) {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: indycascade <in> <out>");
      System.exit(2);
    }

    Job job = new Job(getConf());
    Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration();

    // insert other job set up here

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
  }
}
```

Final point - any reference to `conf` after you create the `Job` instance will be the original conf. Job makes a deep copy of the conf object, so calling `MultipleOutputs.addNamedoutput(conf, ...)` will not have the desired effect, use `MultipleOutputs.addNamedoutput(job.getConfiguration(), ...)` instead. See my example code above for the correct way to do this